# how to add a new column to a dataframe in python and insert d/f values in it for d/f rows?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe(df1) in python :

```
          ID       Date      Time     XYZ
0        GP3   2016-01-08  16:00:00    64   
1        GP2   2016-01-08  16:00:00   557   
2        GP4   2016-01-08  16:00:00   747   
3        GP1   2016-01-08  16:00:00   406   
4        EP3   2016-01-08  16:00:00    64
```

I want to add another column 'ABC' in it, having d/f values(which are being pulled from another dictionary(dict1), based on the 'ID' in dataframe)

```
          ID       Date      Time      XYZ     ABC
0        GP3   2016-01-08  16:00:00     64      23
1        GP2   2016-01-08  16:00:00    557      45
2        GP4   2016-01-08  16:00:00    747      56
3        GP1   2016-01-08  16:00:00    406      89
4        EP3   2016-01-08  16:00:00     64      14
```

I tried following:

```
df1["ABC"]=[0]*df1.shape[0]
for i in df1.iterrows():
   i[1][4]  = dict1[i[1][0]]   # dict1[i[1][0]] gives the desired int values
```

But, I am not able to update the values of 'ABC' in the dataframe. They are all coming as 0. How to update all the values?
dict1 :

```
dict1={'GP1':89,'GP2':45,'GP3':23,'GP4':56,'EP3':14}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) method:

```
df1['ABC'] = df1['ID'].map(dict1)

df1
Out[7]: 
    ID       Date      Time  XYZ  ABC
0  GP3 2016-01-08  16:00:00   64   23
1  GP2 2016-01-08  16:00:00  557   45
2  GP4 2016-01-08  16:00:00  747   56
3  GP1 2016-01-08  16:00:00  406   89
4  EP3 2016-01-08  16:00:00   64   14
```

If you have extra elements in ID series, it will return NaN. If you want to change them with a default value, you can use, for example,  `.fillna(0)` at the end. If you want the original values from the ID series, use `.fillna(df1['ID'])` instead.